# How do I change accordion header with plus and minus symbol?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't like the default Accordion icons and I want to change them. This link here:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/#option-header

shows the option to change the header but it requires to specify icons. I don't need icons. I just need a simple `(+)` and `(-)`

How can I do that with accordions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hiya **working sample demo** http://jsfiddle.net/zM5Vj/ **or** http://jsfiddle.net/zM5Vj/show/

Hope this helps, + will be shown when accordion is collapsed where as - in case of open accordion.

have a nice one!

**Jquery code** which adds + and - accordingly Rest full code is in fiddle, If you want I can copy paste the whole code. Please let me know how it goes!

```
$(function(){
 $('#accordion .fullChild>a.opener').text('+').addClass('box');

  $('#accordion .opener').click(function() {
  if($(this).text() == "-") {
  $(this).text("+");
  }
  else {
  $('#accordion .opener').text("+");
  $(this).text("-");
  }
});
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I require. I am unable to vote you. It requires 15 reputation.

Comment: @TimTom MAGIC you are +15 now :) Glad it helped!

Comment: I'll vote by you! He deserves by being fast as hell providing useful and complete answers!